# Failed to map memory in the client: Out of memory android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have list in the main activity.
Every click on the list item, it opens the activity with the webview. My scenario is:
click on the list item, open the activity with webview,
it loaded, than I press the hardware back button of the phone and I am again on main activity.
This scenario I repeat more times (30). After that my application is crashed and I have this error:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL error:  Out of memory!
E/qdmemalloc﹕ ion: Failed to map memory in the client: Out of memory
E/qdgralloc﹕ Could not mmap handle 0x60b6560, fd=672 (Out of memory)
E/qdgralloc﹕ gralloc_register_buffer: gralloc_map failed
W/GraphicBufferMapper﹕ registerBuffer(0x60b6560) failed -12 (Out of memory)
E/GraphicBuffer﹕ unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Out of memory (-12)
E/Surface﹕ dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -12
W/Adreno-EGLSUB﹕ <DequeueBuffer:736>: dequeue native buffer fail: Out of memory, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include `android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest file, under the `application` tag.

Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application. It only applies to the first application loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results.

Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

[largeHeap documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

Comment: I already included `android:largeHeap="true"` and that not helped me.

Comment: Try overriding `onBackPressed()` method in the Activity with WebView,
and call `finish();` inside it.
The activity will get destroyed and there won't be memory issues.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I found what is the problem, the webview in android 5.0 or above has issues [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539373)